# finding exact match of the text by using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i would like to extract the exact matching value of text from html by using beautifulsoup.But i am getting some almost matching text with my exact text.
my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2enter code here
url="http://www.somesite.com"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
for elem in soup(text=re.compile("exact text")):
   print elem
```

for the above mentioned code output is like:

```
1.exact text
2.almost exact text
```

how can i get only the exact match by using beautifulsoup?
note:the variable(elem) should be in  `<class 'bs4.element.Comment'>`type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`'s  `find_all` method with its `string` argument for this.

As an example, here I parse a small page from wikipedia about a place in Jamaica. I look for all strings whose texts are 'Jamaica stubs' but I expect to find just one. When I find it I display the text and its parent.

```
>>> url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassava_Piece'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get(url).text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> for item in soup.find_all(string="Jamaica stubs"):
...     item
...     item.findParent()
... 
'Jamaica stubs'
<a href="/wiki/Category:Jamaica_stubs" title="Category:Jamaica stubs">Jamaica stubs</a>
```

On second thoughts, after reading the comment, a better way would be:

```
>>> url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> import re
>>> page = requests.get(url).text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> for i, item in enumerate(soup.find_all(string=re.compile('women', re.IGNORECASE))):
...     i, item.findParent().text[:100]
... 
(0, "Women's Bandy World Championships")
(1, "The governing body is the 126-member International Hockey Federation (FIH). Men's field hockey has b")
(2, 'The governing body of international play is the 77-member International Ice Hockey Federation (IIHF)')
(3, "women's")
```

I use `IGNORECASE` in the regex so that both 'Women' and 'women' are found in the wikipedia article. I use `enumerate` in the `for` loop so that I can number the items that are displayed to make them easier to read.

Comment: thanks for your help..
the above mentioned code is not working for me. `soup.find_all(string="Jamaica stubs"): `   returns nothing.

Comment: You'd better provide an example, or some examples, of HTML that you're trying to search.

Comment: I think I've offered an improvement in the second version.

Comment: `for elem in soup.find_all(text="Tullus"):
print elem` is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can search at your `soup` for the desired element, using it's `tag` and any `attribute` value.

I.e.: this code will search for all `a` elements with `id` equal to `some_id_value`.

Then it'll `loop` each element found, testing if it's `.text` value is equal to `"exact text"`.

If so, it'll print the whole `element`.

```
for elem in soup.find_all('a', {'id':'some_id_value'}):
    if elem.text == "exact text":
        print(elem)
```

Comment: thanks for your response...i just want to search for  occurrence of the text without using any tags..